# 2 way pipe communication. hang

Tags: c, fork, pipe, parent-child

I am trying to get the parent to send information to the child, and for the child to send it back, using 2 file descriptors.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define READ 0
#define WRITE 1 
int main(void) {

  int fdWrite[2];
  int fdRead[2];
  int pid, i, num;
  FILE* output;

  if (pipe(fdRead) == -1) {
    perror("Can't create pipe");
    exit(1);
  }

  if (pipe(fdWrite) == -1) {
    perror("Can't create pipe");
    exit(1);
  }

  char mystring[100] = { 0 };

  char c;

  pid = fork();
  if (pid) {
    FILE * read;
    FILE * write;
    close(fdRead[WRITE]);
    close(fdWrite[READ]);

    write = fdopen(fdWrite[WRITE], "w");
    fprintf(write, "parent %s\n", "jeronimooo...");

    read = fdopen(fdRead[READ], "r");
    fgets(mystring, 100, read);
    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", mystring);

  } else {
    /* child */
    dup2(fdRead[WRITE], STDOUT_FILENO);
    close(fdRead[READ]);
    close(fdRead[WRITE]);

    dup2(fdWrite[READ], STDIN_FILENO);
    close(fdWrite[READ]);
    close(fdWrite[WRITE]);

    fgets(mystring, 100, stdin);
    fprintf(stdout, "child %s\n", mystring);

  }
  exit(0);
}
```

What I'm trying to do:

1. Write, to a file descriptor in parent, that is read by its receiving descriptor.
2. Then in another descriptor, send the information from the child to its receiving descriptor in the parent.

Currently is hangs on line: `fgets(mystring,100, read)`.

Comment: Hangs on *which* `fgets` call? There are two.

Comment: Also, I don't know what buffering mode `fdopen` uses, you might want to check that so it's not full buffered. Try `fflush` after writing?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, THANKS! can you explain why fflush works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C I/O streams are normally *buffered*, that means that when you do e.g. `fprintf` then what you print to the stream isn't actually written to the file, it's written into an in-memory buffer. When the buffer is full then the data in it is actually written to the file. The [`fflush`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fflush) function *flushes* the buffer, i.e. it takes what's in the buffer and writes it immediately to the file.

The problem here is that when you do `fdopen` then the file stream is created with full buffering (unlike the line buffering of e.g. `stdout`) so the buffer really has to be filled for it to be actually written. By explicitly force it to be written, the other end of the pipe can read it.

Comment: or `setvbuf(3)` to change the buffer type explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

```
the following is  an excerpt for how to use a pipe, 
extracted from a working system
where this pipe was used to kick a hardware watchdog
In general, this example only contains the code needed to :
create pipe, fork, write pipe, read pipe.

typedef struct
{
    struct timespec time;
    int tracking_number;
    long magic;
} WatchdogRecord;

WatchdogRecord watchdog_record;
pid_t  childpid;
int watchdog_pipe[2];

// open the pipe
pipe(watchdog_pipe);

// Set both ends of pipe to nonblocking
for(pipe_end=0; pipe_end<2; pipe_end++)
{
    // Get previous flags
    int f = fcntl(watchdog_pipe[pipe_end], F_GETFL, 0);

    // Set bit for non-blocking flag
    f |= O_NONBLOCK;

    // Change flags on fd
    fcntl(watchdog_pipe[pipe_end], F_SETFL, f);

} // for each pipe_end

// fork the child process
if ((childpid = fork()) == -1)
{ // then fork failed

    perror("fork");
    exit(1);
}

// implied else, fork successful

if (childpid == 0)
{ // then child process

    // child closes up 'write' side of pipe
    close(watchdog_pipe[1]);


        // if any pipe input then store it
        while (((readret = read(watchdog_pipe[0],
                 readbuffer+nbytes, 
                 sizeof(readbuffer)-nbytes)) != -1) 
              && 
                ((nbytes+=readret) >= sizeof(WatchdogRecord)))
        {
            wdrec = (WatchdogRecord *)readbuffer;

            // check magic number to make sure record is aligned properly in pipe
            if (wdrec->magic == WD_MAGIC)
            {
                // read a full record, so reset nbytes to 0
                nbytes = 0;
                wd_syncerror = 0;

                // and clear magic so it will have to be 
                // rewritten validly by the next read
                wdrec->magic = 0L;
            }

            else // try to resynchronize
            {
                log_error("WDPipe Out Of Sync!, magic=0x%p\n", wdrec->magic);

                //drop one of nbytes and wait for next try to resync
                nbytes = 1;

                // if this happens too many times, die
                if (++wd_syncerror > sizeof(WatchdogRecord))
                {
                    log_error("WDPipe Out Of Sync Too Long!\n");
                    watchdog_die();

                } // ? too many sync errors


                // fill in temporary info for wdrec so we don't use bad data
                wdrec->time = curtime;
                wdrec->tracking_number = -1;

            } // pipe out of sync 
}
else
{ // else parent process

    // parent closes 'read' side of pipe
    close(watchdog_pipe[0]);


// send message through pipe,
// remember pipe has no concept of record, 
// so include a 'marker' so receiver can find edge of record
watchdog_record.time = curtime;
watchdog_record.tracking_number = tracking_number;
watchdog_record.magic = WD_MAGIC;
write(watchdog_pipe[1], &watchdog_record, sizeof(WatchdogRecord));
```